# I wanted to enter a command line argument for my string

Tags: java, netbeans-7

```
public class NewClass1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {

        String datasetFile = args[0];
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(datasetFile));
}
}
```

It generated the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: abc (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at JavaApplication.NewClass1.main(NewClass1.java:29)
```

Should  I replace it with this code?

```
BufferedReader out = new BufferedReader(new 
                      InputStreamReader(System.in));
String input = out.readLine();
```

Comment: This link might be helpful :http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~donnie/cs11/java/java-main.html

Comment: Thank you the link was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a command line arguments [tutorial for netbeans](http://netbeanside61.blogspot.com/2009/02/using-command-line-arguments-in.html).  Basically, you go:

> File->Project Properties->Run->Arguments.

In your code, you should probably have:

```
try
{
       if (args.length != 0)
       {
           datasetFile = args[0];
           in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(datasetFile));
       }
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Your question asks how to enter command line arguments, but it looks like the way you did it worked, since you got a `FileNotFoundException` on `abc`, so that's your issue.

Comment: It says the file was not found.  That's your error.  Is the file "abc" in the same directory?  If it's not, you need to pass its absolute path, ie ~/Users/Steve/Desktop/test.txt or C:\\Users\\Steve\\Desktop\\test.txt.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get just means that the file 'abc' does not exist. There is nothing wrong with your code.